# Is there a "checkout" on SE, especially for deleted questions/rants?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, undelete

Stack Exchange is addictive, and has an audience that could make a change. Although there are strict guidelines in place in most communities over here, we are all human, and sometimes we post ranting questions that deviate from the guidelines, and are not acceptable on these sites.

Such questions get closed, and, after a while, some of them disappear not only from the public view on the site, but also from the private view of the users who asked them. This final deletion appears to be somewhat random, and even happens to good-quality writeups, without any notification to the person affected.

This is not fair. Most of these ranting questions have received substantial attention from the asker, and deleting it without a trace is simply not fair to the person asking. I'd like to be able to repost these rants or controversial topics into my blog. I don't feel good that they are taken from me under my feet instead.

Comment: I agree users should get to see their deleted content for at least a while, but the logical solution to this problem is to simply make a copy of your contribution before posting it, as suggested by Bathsheba below.

Comment: Users who have the URL for their question (which they can check their profile for) can still view it even if it's deleted, @Pekka.

Comment: That folks don't have the presence of mind to preserve their rants beforehand is both indicative of their relative usefulness, and characteristic of their impulsive nature.  Neither attribute is desirable.

Answer (score 10):

Doing so would hardly *discourage* ranting.

Why not save a private copy of your *rant* in advance?

Comment: Why not save a private copy of your rant *instead* of posting it to SO?

Comment: Some rants may have legitimate answers.

Comment: @cnst If it's a legitimate question with a legitimate answer, it should not be worded as a rant.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, they're not worded as rants; one of my questions was simply deleted after I -1'ed an answer that didn't address my concern.  Other questions are reopened.  Maybe I don't have time to address one closed question right now, and then I come back another month, and the question is already taken from under my feet.

Comment: If it was recently deleted, should you not still see it under "Recently deleted questions" @cnst? At the bottom of your questions list.

Comment: I didn't realise it was going to be removed in its entirety, since the question by itself was valid, it simply couldn't have had any answer at the time.  For example, my personal finance question about foreign transactions being declined.

Comment: @cnst there's an automatic delete script as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/213963).